# privatemsg and services fully integration

Tags: services, privatemsg

Does there exist any module even sandbox or starting point module (not ublished on drupal.org) to help achieve privatemsg crud operations over services module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exist a sandbox project [pm services](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/deminy/2413647) clone comand

```
git clone --branch 7.x-1.x    https://git.drupal.org/sandbox/deminy/2413647.git privatemsg_services
```

cd privatemsg_services

also  [pm services(profile2)](https://www.drupal.org/files/pm_service.tar__0.gz) but it needs profile2 to be enabled beore

Comment: I have written this command

` $ git clone --branch 7.x-1.x http//git.drupal.org/sandbox/deminy/t 13647.git `    

and Got this Error

` fatal: repository 'http//git.drupal.org/sandbox/deminy/t' does not exist`

Comment: @Sara I added the full clone command as the first one was encoded  and my be broken, Try keda!

Answer (score 1):

The current discussion on integrating Privatemsg for Drupal 7 and Services can be found [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/433780).